# missing ; before statement in below

Tags: javascript, salesforce, apex-code

I am getting error in this code.

```js
if (pbrecords[0].Pricebook2.Name == 'Standard Price Book') {


  var tradingPforms1 = '{!$Label.FXT_TradingPForms1_JS}';


  var SplitResult = tradingPforms1.split(",");
  var strqry = '';
  for (i = 0; i < SplitResult.length; i++) {
    if (strqry == '') {

      strqry = strqry + "'" + SplitResult[i];
    } else {
      strqry = strqry + "','" + SplitResult[i];
    }
  }

}
```

Hi i am getting error misssing ; before statement

Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you show what is in `SplitResult` ?

Comment: you need to check the other part of code just before this to check this error.